# Request for a new tag for the Clarity smart contract language

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

I would like to request a new tag for the [Clarity smart contract language](https://clarity-lang.org/). There is a very active and growing community developing code in this language, but it is hard to distinguish questions about it on SO (clarity is an often used word obviously).

I propose to use create the tag `[clarity-lang]` as [clarity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clarity) is already in use for something completely different.

How does a proposal for a new tag work?

Comment: You already have 1.5K+ reputation, so you can already create tags yourself.

Comment: Tags cannot exist without questions. You need to tag existing questions with it directly.

Comment: I don't see a good reason to discuss this one. It might be a good idea to burninate/disambiguate the clarity tag since it refers to multiple distinct products that mostly have their own tag, but that's a separate issue

Comment: Thanks everyone. Sorry for not finding the FAQ there...